# Handle a post request in react

Tags: reactjs, http-post

I am writing a react app that will receive some data from another data via a post. So I am trying to handle a post request. I am a newbie in React and I would appreciate an example on the topic.

Thank you

Comment: *receive some data from another data via a post* is a little bit unclear but I think I got what you're saying. It's all in their docs https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html. Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In my react app, I am redirecting to another application. The other application gathers some data and post a response back to my reactApp. I am trying to handle the response body sent in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at fetching, you can see references here: 
https://reactjs.org/community/data-fetching.html
fetch is native to react. You also have Axios which is more advanced but can give you functionality like promises and cancelling requests.

infomration on Axios can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Regards

Aaron